# Modal popup extender not working inside asp:content

Tags: asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a modal popup extender inside asp:content page. It was working fine until yesterday.  I I am not sure what changes I made to break it. I would appreciate it if someone can look at it and point me in the right direction.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="sectioncontent" Runat="Server">
 <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Show" />
 <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button5" PopupControlID="Panel1" CancelControlID="Button1" >
                        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="65px"  >
    <p>
       The following records will be deleted from this Cluster</p>

 Comments:  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" 
            Text="Submit" onclick="Button3_Click" />
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            Text="Cancel" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Also, page is loading when I am clicking the Show button.

Comment: I can't count the number of times I had issues like that using the ajax control toolkit. I finally decided that it was not worth the weight and pain and moved to jquery where I knew what was going on.

Comment: @BrettWeber lol you are right here I hate .net ajax. I too have problem with Calandarextender that has disappeared suddenly after working for months. and am searching how to fix it. :( lol.. aspx sometimes looks to have overhaul of jquery now.

Comment: This is one of my reasons for choosing to limit my use of aspx and .net technologies. Most of the time it's not needed, and easier soing it yourself or somewhere else.